# Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.EHS_Task__c'

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I am getting error "Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.EHS_Task__c'" while deploying VF page. Below is the page code:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;border-right: 1px solid gray;padding: 2px 10px;">
                    <strong class="" >Task:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="frminput" value = "{!getEHS.EHS_Task__c}"></input>
                </div>
```

Controller:

```
public  class ES_EHSReportGeneration {


    public Apexpages.Standardcontroller cntrl ;     
    public PageReference page; 
    public String id ='' ;
    public List<EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c> getEHS{get;set;}
 
public ES_EHSReportGeneration(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.cntrl = controller ; 
            this.page = ApexPages.currentPage();
            this.id = page.getParameters().get('id');
               
}   

 public ES_EHSReportGeneration(){

    getEHS = [Select id, EHS_Task__c from EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c where id= :id limit 1] ; 


}
```

Please check and advise what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c> getEHS{get;set;}
```

This is a list of items. You need to access the zeroth index:

```
<input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="frminput" 
  value="{!getEHS[0].EHS_Task__c}" />
```

At this point, you'd get an *index out of bounds* error if no record is found. I'd refactor this to use a single variable instead of a List.

Note that you also don't even need the query here, as the Standard Controller interface gives you the record with the data you need if you don't use variable like `getEHS`.

```
<input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="frminput" 
  value="{!EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c.EHS_Task__c}" />
```

By using the object's name, the Visualforce controller will automatically include it in a query that it does automatically for Visualforce pages.